# Matlab Can't reload library in MATLAB/R2011b/bin/glnxa64/

Tags: matlab, fortran, gfortran

[image]I got the following problem when running "`imresize`":

> MATLAB:dispatcher:loadLibrary Can't load '/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011b/bin/glnxa64/libmwmathlinalg.so': libgfortran.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.

The file `libmwmathlinalg.so` is located in that folder but Matlab cannot find it.  It is likely many other .so files are not accessible either so it's a big problem. I suspect that this is caused by a bad linking. Yesterday I wanted to mex a fortran code, and I did the following

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/local/MATLAB/R2011b/sys/os/glnxa64 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2011b/bin/glnxa64/libgfortran.so.3
```

Later when Matlab restarted I found the problem. I have removed the link using

```
sudo rm /usr/local/MATLAB/R2011b/sys/os/glnxa64/libgfortran.so.3
```

But the problem persists. I think that maybe the folder

```
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011b/sys/os/glnxa64
```

should be somehow linked to

```
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011b/bin/glnxa64
```

but it's not doing so. Any ideas?

Edit: Actually, could anybody upload a screenshot about the files (including links) inside the

```
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011b/sys/os/glnxa64
```

folder? That may be helpful. I've shown mine here.

Comment: I think libgfortran.so.3 should be linked to libgfortran.so.3.0.0. Both in same directory. Do you have this?

Comment: I have libgfortran.so.3.0.0, and remember having done so. The main problem was libmwmathlinalg.so cannot be found.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by removing and installing again the whole Matlab 2011. Trivial and non-trivial...